# How to access protected lastPage property from result set

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, pagination

I am using laravel 4.2 and for some reason i need to access the `lastPage` property in my view which I failed. Here is the code of my controller when paginating.

```
$products = Product::where('status', '=', 'available')->paginate(20);
```

Below is a part of `var_dump($products)` in my view file and i need to know how to access it the correct way.

```
  protected 'total' => int 10491
  protected 'hasMore' => null
  protected 'perPage' => int 20
  protected 'currentPage' => int 1
  protected 'lastPage' => int 525
  protected 'from' => int 1
  protected 'to' => int 20
```

Comment: if I'm not wrong, you're actually looking to call the nonprotected method `->getLastPage()` which will return the value of `lastPage`. *edit* I'm not wrong, you can find it in [the documentation here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/pagination). Cntrl +f "getLastPage"

Comment: @Ohgodwhy thank you. that is great. I indeed access it using '$products->getLastPage()'. Can you please answer it not in comment so I can mark it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I should've answered it below.

You'll want to use the nonprotected method `->getLastPage()` in order to access that protected method.

You can check in the [documentation here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/pagination).

Comment: Very useful. now I don't have to go through many lines of codes to access it. Thanks !